Metrics for comparision of web application security testing tools (DAST)
I'm currently working on a thesis comparing web application security (WAS) testing tools. I'm struggling to determine which metrics to use for comparison. Could you provide any suggestions for metrics?
I'm seeking input from security professionals to suggest suitable metrics for comparison.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You dont like easy problems do you ;)
This is a really hard one.
You can focus on features - what the tools actually support. That is realtively easy, but it doesnt tell you how good they actually are.
The best way is to test them against real world applications, ideally ones with known vulnerabilities. That will take you a long time.
You can test them against deliberately vulnerable apps, but many vendors will tune their tools to make sure they work well with these apps.
Creating your own test apps is a good option, but thats also hard and time consuming.
The best attempt at this I know of is https://github.com/sectooladdict/wavsep - its not been updated for a long time, I know it took Shay a lot of time when he maintained it.
I'm v happy to have a chat about this if you like - I'm the ZAP project lead so I have a definite interest in this area :) https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/team/psiinon/
